# Python pathlib: Resolve full path to symbolic link without following it

Tags: python, path, os.path, pathlib

Let's say I have a link`/home/me/folder/link` that points to `/home/me/target`. 
When I call

```
pathlib.Path("link").resolve()
```

from `/home/me/folder/`, it will return the resolved path to the **target**, not the resolved path of the link. 
How can I get the latter using `pathlib` (there don't seem to be any options for `resolve()`)?

(with `os.path` the equivalent of what I'm looking for would be`os.path.abspath("link")`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pathlib.Path` has an `absolute` method that does what you want.

```
$  mkdir folder
$  touch target
$  ln -s ~/target ~/folder/link
$  ls -l folder/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me users 16 Feb 20 19:47 link -> /home/me/target
$  cd folder

$/folder  python3.7 -c 'import os.path;print(os.path.abspath("link"))'
/home/me/folder/link

$/folder  python3.7 -c 'import pathlib;p = pathlib.Path("link");print(p.absolute())'
/home/me/folder/link
```

The method doesn't appear in the module documentation, but its [docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80cc10fa7d5f41daaf59ae9173022303f35a403c/Lib/pathlib.py#L1140) reads:

> Return an absolute version of this path.  This function works
> even if the path doesn't point to anything.
> No normalization is done, i.e. all '.' and '..' will be kept along.
> Use resolve() to get the canonical path to a file.

It's worth noting that there are comments in the method code (in the 3.7 branch) that suggest it may not be fully tested on all platforms.